# Chrome ignores Content-Disposition filename

Tags: php, google-chrome

I have following code in File xyz.php :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition:inline;filename="hello.txt"');
echo "hello world";
?>
```

The page opens inside the webbrowser due to its Content-Type.
But when I try to save the file using Ctrl+S, Firefox and IE are saving the file as "hello.txt", but Chrome saves the page as "xyz.txt".

What can I do so that the file is saved with its original file name using Chrome?